# Storing Tuple values in list of Class Objects

Tags: python

I have a python code that extracts info from database. The results are stored in a tuple within a list. I would like to store the tuple information in a class object. Since there are more than one result returned from query, I want to use List of class Object. I do not know how to assign value. Below is the snippet:

```
#Class
class StudentDetails():
    def __init__(self, id, Name, Status):
        self.id= id
        self.Name= Name        
        self.Status= Status

def main():

    results= LinkCursor.fetchall() #databse results
```

The result is of form list:
[(1, 'XYZ', 'P'), (2, 'ABC', 'P'), (3, 'DEF', 'A'), (4, 'MNO', 'P')]

In Summary, I want to store result in different Class objects, 
Student1 =StudentDetails(1, 'XYZ', 'P') 
Student2 =StudentDetails(2, 'ABC', 'P')

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share your expected output to make [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To begin with, `StuduentDetails` will fail since it won't be able to find `LinkName` and `LinkStatus`

Comment: Hi Chris, Noted! 
In Summary, I want to store result in different Class objects, 
Student1 =StudentDetails(1, 'XYZ', 'P')
Student1 =StudentDetails(2, 'ABC', 'P')

Comment: And how do you want to store those different Class object? is `list` sufficient?

Comment: Yes Chris, List of class objects of class StudentDetails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate your list of tuples while instantiating `StudentDetails`:

```
l = [(1, 'XYZ', 'P'), (2, 'ABC', 'P'), (3, 'DEF', 'A'), (4, 'MNO', 'P')]
my_students = [StudentDetails(*tup) for tup in l]
my_students
# [<__main__.StudentDetails at 0x7fea5a8259b0>,
#  <__main__.StudentDetails at 0x7fea5a825208>,
#  <__main__.StudentDetails at 0x7fea5a825cf8>,
#  <__main__.StudentDetails at 0x7fea5a825cc0>]

my_students[0].Name
# 'XYZ'

my_students[1].Name
# 'ABC
```

Or you can use `dict`:

```
d = {"Student%s" %i : StudentDetails(*tup) for i, tup in enumerate(l)}
d['Student1'].Name
# 'XYZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works with your question.

```
class StudentDetails():
    def __init__(self, id=1, Name="manoj", Status="Active"):
        self.id= id
        self.LinkName= Name        
        self.LinkStatus= Status
li = [(1, 'XYZ', 'P'), (2, 'ABC', 'P'), (3, 'DEF', 'A'), (4, 'MNO', 'P')]
list_obj = []
for i in list:
    student_details = StudentDetails()
    student_details.id = i[0]
    student_details.LinkName = i[1]
    student_details.LinkStatus = i[2]
    list_obj.append(student_details)
```

Comment: hi Manoj, I wanted to store values of result in class object

Comment: Its my pleasure